# Augmentation ideal of a free group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

If $F$ is a free group then it has cohomological dimension one, which implies that the augmentation ideal $IF=\operatorname{ker}(\epsilon:\mathbb{Z}G\to \mathbb{Z})$ of its group ring is a projective $\mathbb{Z}F$-module. Hence $IF$ is a direct summand of a free $\mathbb{Z}F$-module $M$.

> Question: Is it possible to give an explicit construction of such a free module $M$? Perhaps it has a basis related to a free basis of $F$?

Comment: The answer is yes.  Use the chain complex for the Cayley graph of F to see it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $X$ be a free basis for $F$.  The Cayley graph of $F$ is a tree $T$ on which $F$ acts freely.  The augmented chain complex gives a resolution
$$0\to \mathbb ZF^{(X)}\to \mathbb ZF\to \mathbb Z\to 0$$ (since $T$ is a tree) where we identify $\mathbb ZF^{(X)}$ as the free abelian group on the edges of $T$ and the image of the boundary map sends the edge $(g,x)$ to $gx-x$ and is hence the augmentation ideal (which in any event is clearly the kernel of the augmentation map).  So the augmentation ideal is a free module on $X$ with generators $x-1$ with $x\in X$.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!

Comment: I think more generally a free group is a FIR so all left ideals are free.  But the free generating set is more complicated to describe